# python selenium cache refreshing value before change again

Tags: python, html, selenium, web, selenium-webdriver

In my Selenium-Python project, there is a page with some tables. the value of cell's of this tables, change every 2-3 second's.
i want to do some stuff with value's of cell's like color and text. but i get this error

> Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
>   for example in this code before i can fetch all rows, new table comes up and error happen:

```
usids = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'usid')]")

for x in range(len(usids)):
     if usids[x].get_attribute("class").find("names") != -1:
         print(usids[x].text)
```

how can i fix it?

Comment: Include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your questions, please.

Comment: @AmitaiIrron edited. Thanks